# Getting data from a object named $type

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have this in response from a webservice

```
stdClass Object (
    [$type] => Model.Result[[System.Int32, mscorlib]], Model
    [success] => 1
    [errorMessage] =>
    [result] => 1
    [statusCode] => 200
)
```

and i have tried `$response->{"$type"}['success']` and `$response->{"$type"}->success` and failed - i can loop through the object and get the value, but it should be possible to get i directly.

Comment: @Rizier123 , i think this question is different than your marked question, can you give it a minute and look at the problem

Comment: try with single quotes like `$response->{'$type'}['success']`

Comment: @Viral Maybe it's just: `$response->success` ...

Comment: i just need to echo $response->success  the $type confused me - sorry :-)

Comment: @Viral http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070686/getting-data-from-a-object-named-type#comment50160436_31070686 <- See

Comment: you are right @Rizier123